# Is Javascript's class method instantiated?

Tags: javascript, class, memory-management

For example, if I have a class `ImageBlock` and then that class has a complex method `modifyImage()`...

```js
class ImageBlock {
  /* ... */

  modifyImage() {
    // A 40+ line code, complex code
  }  

  /* ... */
}
```

When I create a new instance of `ImageBlock`, will `modifyImage()` will be instantiated too? as another function?

I don't want have two instance of complex method, as it was memory waste.

Comment: The way you write it, there will be only one function for that, `ImageBlock.prototype.modifyImage`. And if you have two instances, unless you override the function, you'll get `instance1.modifyImage === instance2.modifyImage`.

Comment: Lines don't equate to memory. The only way to know what the impact will be is to profile the memory usage of your app in testing. If you determine that this has a meaningful impact, then you can create a [static method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/static) instead.

Comment: @jsejcksn I don't ask for alternative. Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> as another function?

No, it'll be the exact same function.

```js
class ImageBlock {
  /* ... */

  modifyImage() {
    // A 40+ line code, complex code
  }  

  /* ... */
}

const i1 = new ImageBlock();
const i2 = new ImageBlock();
console.log(
  i1.modifyImage === i2.modifyImage
);
```

Methods defined inside a class are put onto the prototype object, *once*, and then each instance has an internal prototype of that prototype object.

That said, even if it *was* created anew each time (such as with a class field arrow function in order to preserve reference to `this` inside - which is reasonably common) -

> as it was memory waste.
>
> A 40+ line code

it would be absolutely nothing to worry about in 99.9% of situations. Computers from the past decade can run many thousands of lines in the blink of an eye, and simply *creating* a function without calling it is much easier than that.